# Get the last Thursday, but only if it's the second Thursday in this sequence

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, strtotime

I know I can get the last Thursday with this

```
$firstdate = strtotime('last thursday');
```

However, as of the time posting this question it will return

```
August 2nd, 2012
```

What I need is the last Thursday that follows this two week cycle:

- August 9
- August 23
- September 6
- September 20

And every second Thursday after that.

- So if the current date is August 10, it will return August 9
- If the current date is August 21, it will also return August 9 (even though the previous Thursday is August 16)
- If the current date is August 24, it will return August 23
- If the current date is Sept 1, it will also return August 23 (even though the previous Thursday is August 30)

Comment: A two week cycle starting from when?

Comment: From the last Thursday from how, up to two weeks ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the week number.

What you want are Thursdays of the weeks which have an **even number**.

Here is one way to do it:

```
function getLastEvenWeekThursday()
{
    $lastThursday = strtotime('last thursday');
    $weeknumber = date("W", $lastThursday);
    if($weeknumber % 2 == 0)
        return $lastThursday;
    else
        return $lastThursday - 3600*24*7;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you!